# Next.js second query parameter is missing

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I have a request which is like "xxxx.com/api/xxx?url=wwww.xxx.com?id=abc"
With this kind of URL at the end '=abc' value is missing. I know the reason because there is no & before the second query but the thing is I can not change the current value. How can I get the missing value?

Answer (score 1):

Your url is not correct, multiple query parameters should be used with `&` not extra `?`
Change it like this: `xxxx.com/api/xxx?url=wwww.xxx.com&id=abc`

Comment: users are sending the URL as a parameter that is the reason I can not change it

Answer (score 0):

Gather them inside an array

```
console.log('searchParams', searchParams);

const p = searchParams?.url ? searchParams.url.toString().split('?') : [];
console.log('p', p);

const values: any = [];

for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
  if (p[i].indexOf('=') > -1) {
    values.push({ key: p[i].split('=')[0], value: p[i].split('=')[1] });
  } else values.push({ key: 'url', value: p[i] });
}
console.log('values, values)
```

input query params -> ?url=wwww.xxx.com?id=abc

result -> [ { key: 'url', value: 'wwww.xxx.com' }, { key: 'id', value: 'abc' } ]